# I want to get row where column 'count' > 0 and other columns match substring

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

I am trying to execute a query:

```
select * from book where name like '%txt%' or author like '%txt%' and count>0
```

but the resulting rows also contain rows with `count = 0`

Any help?

Comment: Consider changing from a reserved word `count` or putting bactics around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parentheses:

```
where (name like '%txt%' or author like '%txt%') and
      count > 0
```

And perhaps a refresher on boolean logic and operator precedence.

Your code is interpreted as:

```
where name like '%txt%' or
      (author like '%txt%' and count > 0)
```

Because `and` has higher precedence than `or`.